# Repeating Excel Formula every N rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add a repeating formula in Excel that will sum a range of values in another column (scores) for each subject to get a Total Score for each subject.

I have added the following formula which seems to total the values correctly:

SUM(OFFSET($AO$2,(ROW()-424)*424,0,424,1))

You can see it here
[image: ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DIjK.png]

Here is the result I currently have from adapting the formula...

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB5kT.png)

Does anyone know how can I get this formula to repeat every 425 rows in this column (AQ)?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: use a Union of the cells and apply the formula to the union.

Comment: @Jeeped even I don't know what you mean with that.

Comment: @teylyn - `set rng = union(cells(425, "AQ"), cells(850, "AQ"), cells(1275, "AQ"))` then `rng.formula = "SUM(OFFSET($AO$2,(ROW()-424)*424,0,424,1))"` The union could be aggregated in a For ... Next loop.

Comment: Ah, but only if the formula is applied using VBA.

Comment: @teylyn - ... but I wouldn't use the OFFSET function and would probably just run a formula that checks the MOD of the row all the ways down the column (leaving a zero-length string if not multiple of 425).

Comment: @teylyn - Yes, there was only an [tag:excel] and [tag:excel-vba] associated with the question.

Comment: That's what I just posted.

Comment: I get the gist, but I am not following entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this formula in cell AQ2 and copy down:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,425),"",SUM(OFFSET($AO$2,(ROW()-424)*424,0,424,1)))
```

It will perform the calculation only in every 425th row, starting in row 426. You can use a `0` instead of the `""` and format the range not to show zeros.

Edit: Your Offset formula is not correctly calculating the range of the 424 cells preceding the current row. It is a bit too complicated. You can start in the current row and use a negative number in the row offset, like this:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,425),"",SUM(OFFSET(AO2,-424,0,424,1)))
```

So, from the current row, go 424 rows up, then use a range that has 424 rows. That will sum the 424 rows above the current row.

Edit 2: Here is a screenshot with the formula working on column BE instead of AQ.
Rows between the pertinent rows have been hidden.

[image]

The sample file can be accessed here:

https://1drv.ms/x/s!Avd3VBkllUf-7zeMXBcqxfyc9-d-

Comment: Thank you Teylyn. This makes sense. Something is slightly off, in that only the first "Total Score" calculates. The rest are showing as "0."

Comment: I adjusted the formula a few minutes ago. Did you use the current version? Start in row 2 and copy down. The first formula result will show up in row 426.

Comment: Your Offset formula does not seem to work correctly. You claimed it did. So fix the Offset bit.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn. I just used the new one you edited. I'm getting the same result. Total Score is "0" after the first range.

Comment: Well I thought it did work. I am here to get help with the whole formula. I have played around with the offset formula and O'm not sure why its not working.

Comment: I edited my answer and posted a variant with a different Offset approach. That one works.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn. I'm still playing around with it. I just can't get it to work properly. See new image (Image 2) above...

Comment: I edited my post again with a screenshot and a link to a sample file. What version of Excel are you using? Does my sample file work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba),

```
Dim i As Long, rng As Range
With Worksheets("sheet3")
    Set rng = .Cells(426, "AQ")
    For i = 426 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row Step 425
        Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(i, "AQ"))
    Next i
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(r[-424]c41:r[-1]c41)"
End With
```

Comment: This simpler formula seems to work... =IF(MOD(ROW()-1,425),"",SUM(BE2:BE424))        Does this look right?