# Repeating a formula every Nth Row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following command to repeat a formula in Excel every 425th row. It calculates correctly in the first row occurrence, but shows as "0" in all subsequent rows.

=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,425),"",SUM(OFFSET(BE2,(ROW()-424)*424,0,424,1)))

I know there are mistakes in this formula. I did get some help earlier, but it still doesn't seem to work.

[Photo: Issue in context.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzcZb.png)

All good suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: This simpler formula seems to work...          =IF(MOD(ROW()-1,425),"",SUM(BE2:BE424))      Does this look right?

Comment: The code you posted in your comment should work fine. Why do you want to complicate it by using `OFFSET`? Also, edit your question to include any additional information rather than posting it in a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeating Excel Formula every N rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918861/repeating-excel-formula-every-n-rows)